# Gatsby runtime error while using query variable

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

I am using the query variable **slug** for routing for particular page in gatsby. So I am using the template **project-datails.js** for creating page.

So project-datails.js and graphql query variable is looks like this

```
import React from "react"
import Layout from "../components/Layout"
import { graphql } from "graphql"


import * as styles from "../styles/project-details.module.css"


export default function ProjectDetails({ data}) {
  console.log(data)

 
  const { title, stack } = data.markdownRemark.frontmatter
  return (
    <Layout>
      <div className={styles.details}>
        <h2>{title}</h2>
        <h3>{stack}</h3> 
        <h1>Hello</h1>
       </div>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export const query = graphql`
  query ProjectDetails($slug: String) {
    markdownRemark(frontmatter: { slug: { eq: $slug } }) {
      html
      frontmatter {
        stack
        title
        }
    }
  }
`
```

When I log the data its showing **undefined**. When I run the same query on

```
 http://localhost:8000/___graphql
```

Its showing data.

So If I run the template without using the garaphql query variable or without fetching data from garaphql like print only this line inside the template

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

Its working fine.

So when I use the query variable Its showing Run time error.

This query variable **slug** I am passing it from **gatsby-node.js** as this

```
const path = require(`path`)

exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {

  const { data } = await graphql(`
    query Articles {
      allMarkdownRemark {
        nodes {
          frontmatter {
            slug
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  data.allMarkdownRemark.nodes.forEach(node => {
    actions.createPage({
      path: '/projects/'+ node.frontmatter.slug,
      component: path.resolve('./src/templates/Project-details.js'),
      context: {slug: node.frontmatter.slug }
    })
  })

}
```

and The markdownfile **dojo-coffee-house.md** looks like this

```
---
title: The Dojo Coffee House
stack: HTML & CSS
slug: the-dojo-coffee-house
date: 2021-01-01T00:00:00+00:00
thumb: ../images/thumbs/coffee.png
featuredImg: ../images/featured/coffee-banner.png
---

Lorem ninja ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt
```

**UPDATE**

I am getting warning inside my template **project-datails.js** as

```
                                                 
 warning  In page templates only a default export of a valid React component and the named export of a page
query is allowed.
        All other named exports will cause Fast Refresh to not preserve local component state and do a full refresh.

        Please move your other named exports to another file. Also make sure that you only export page queries that
use the "graphql" tag from "gatsby".
  limited-exports-page-templates
```

I am not able to figure whats the error here. So can somebody help ?

Comment: Can you provide the markdown file (and its naming) as well as the full (or the most representative part) of the `gatsby-node.js` file?

Comment: @FerranBuireu I have edited the post. And added full code of  **gatsby-node.js**  file.

Comment: Have you shared all the template (`ProjectDetails`)?

Comment: Yes I have added full code of `PorjectDeatails.js`

Comment: Have you tried using `const` (arrow function) component (`const ProjectDetauls=(props)=>{}`) and then `export default ProjectDetails`? All the research I've done points to a Gatsby version issue, which one are you running?

Comment: Tried with arrow functions but no luck. I am using `gatsby": "^3.0.3"`

Comment: *"Also make sure that you only export page queries that
use the "graphql" tag from "gatsby"."* !!!

Answer (score 0):

import { graphql } from "graphql" -> import { graphql } from "gatsby"

also you need for ProjectDetails do next:

Before:

export default () => ;

After:

function ProjectDetails = () => ;

export default ProjectDetails ;